# What is a good report builder (SQL to HTML & Excel) that can add/remove columns, group columns, filter, etc.?

Tags: sql, reporting

I really like the tool that salesforce has for building reports.  You can choose your categories (aka data tables) and then drag and drop columns into your report, arrange columns etc.  I am looking for an off-the-shelf product that does the same.  Any recommendations? I've attached screen shots of the salesforce tool that has the functionality I want:

http://i53.tinypic.com/msokgg.jpg

http://i56.tinypic.com/2lkd9ft.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one open source solution, [Pentaho](http://www.pentaho.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Or JasperReports... or for non OpenSource, Crystal reports is pretty much the standard.